# MASM x86 Adding two ints

Tags: x86, masm

I am writing a simple program that takes 3 ints from the user and does the following math:

- Sum of the first 2 numbers
- Difference of the second and third numbers
- Product of all three numbers
- Quotient (integer) and remainder of first and third numbers

There should be output to the user showing the calculation. For example, if the user enters 10, 9, and 8, it should show for the first calculation:

10 + 9 = 19

I'm trying to do the sum at the moment. I was able to calculate it, but I seem to be inadvertently overwriting number_1 and number_2 to equal the sum after I add them, so my output is:

19 + 19 = 19

Can anyone help me with what I'm doing wrong here? This is my first week doing assembly so I'm sorry if the answer is super obvious or something...

```
; Sum of first two numbers
mov     eax, number_1
mov     ebx, number_2
add     eax, ebx
mov     sum, eax

; Print results
mov     edx, OFFSET number_1
call    WriteDec
mov     edx, OFFSET op_plus
call    WriteString
mov     edx, OFFSET number_2
call    WriteDec
mov     edx, OFFSET op_equ
call    WriteString
mov     edx, OFFSET sum
call    WriteDec
```

Edit: The issue seems to lie with the textbook author's WriteDec routine that is in a library our professor has us include and use.

Comment: Where are you declaring `number_1_copy` and `number_2_copy`?

Comment: My mistake, I had tried something and forgot to delete that part. It should just be 'number_1' and 'number_2'. Edited post.

Comment: Can you post your `WriteDec` routine? It looks like that might be emitting the value in `EAX` instead of the value pointed to by `EDX`. Just a guess.

Comment: You were right, Mike W. adding a line `mov EAX, sum` before the call to `WriteDec` gave me the right output. The routine was written by my textbook's author and I haven't actually seen it, as it's in a separate library. I will talk to the professor about why it behaves like that.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the library's WriteDec routine appearing to only pull from EAX, it requires an extra line before each attempt to write the numbers.

```
mov eax, (variable-name)
move edx, OFFSET (variable-name)
```

This has solved the issue.